# А есть репозиторий со свежим bind9 для centos7?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, repository, bind9

На VPS с centos 7, кроме родного репозитория CentOS-Base.repo, я установил репозитории epel.repo и remi.repo.
Многие пакеты в них актуальны, например php 7 я всегда на свежую обновляю, включив remi-php74.repo
А вот с bind9 (named) беда - раньше был 9.9.4 Сейчас стал подгружать 9.11.4
Вижу, что у них на сайте https://www.isc.org/bind/ уже стабильная версия 9.16.2 - хотелось бы её попробовать, вроде пишут что там потребление памяти меньше. (bind9 очень прожорлив)

[Changelog](https://fossies.org/linux/misc/dns/bind9/9.16.2/RELEASE-NOTES-bind-9.16.2.pdf)

> The previous DNSSEC sign statistics used lots of memory. The number of
>   keys to track is reduced to four per zone, which should be enough for
>   99% of all signed zones. [GL #1179]

Может есть репозиторий для centos 7 со свежим bind9 9.16.2. Погуглил, но не нашёл.

Comment: А что мешает скачать с сайта, который вы указали в вопросе? https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.16.2/bind-9.16.2.tar.xz